# grub , show menu even with timeout=0

Tags: grub, fedora

The Fedora 15 grub.conf have timeout=0 , so it boots directly to Fedora without showing any grub menu. Is there a way to halt the booting at grub anyway ?

(The issue is an upgraded kernel doesn't boot, and I'd like to just boot the prior kernel version without having to go to a rescue CD and edit grub.conf)

Comment: Try holding the ESC key during boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold ESC right after boot.
I have dual boot with timeout=0, this is the way how I'm getting access to the menu.

Comment: It doesn't work no longer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but just hitting ESC would show me a so called GRUB CLI. It's not a menu but rather a console.
I don't think there is a way to change timeout settings from that GRUB CLI, however, there is a way to instruct it to load specific kernel with specific options.

So, the first thing I did is I printed the current grub config.

```
cat /etc/default/grub
```

It can print too much, so we need some kind of pagination:

```
set pager=1
```

Once we do that, you can find something similar in that output:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.14.27-041427-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.14.27-041427-generic-advanced-f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b' {
recordfail
savedefault
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 4.14.27-041427-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.27-041427-generic root=UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b ro quiet splash loglevel=0 vga=current udev.log-priority=3 fastboot kaslr acpiphp.disable=1 crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M $vt_handoff
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.14.27-041427-generic
```

So, what I did next was I took a photo of everything in that entry, finished pagination until I get back to GRUB CLI.

And started to copy over the commands ignoring 'if' anc 'echo' statements:

```
recordfail
savedefault
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.27-041427-generic root=UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b ro quiet splash loglevel=0 vga=current udev.log-priority=3 fastboot kaslr acpiphp.disable=1 crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.14.27-041427-generic
```

Note: TAB will help you to choose the right linux and initrd, type /boot/vmlinuz and then TAB, you will be prompted with options. Same for initrd, type /boot/initrd and TAB.
The root uuids are very important, make sure you typed them correctly. Also, since I lost my root password I wanted to start a single user recovery mode in order to set the password, so to the end of the `linux xxx` I have added `recovery single`.

The last thing you need to do is to execute in the GRUB CLI:

```
boot
```

That will load the linux using the data provided above. In my case I got to recovery and changed the user password using `passwd` command.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732216/271811) for how to set things up so that the GRUB boot menu is interruptible when timeout=0.